# Remove duplicates while sorting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array containing objects that I need to sort, and remove duplicates based on 3 specific values of each array item. Currently I'm using two loops(NOT nested): 1 to sort, another to remove items. Is there a way to remove duplicates while sorting or something similar? For 1000s of items the following code is quite slow and am wondering if there is a faster way:

```
var list = [
    {a: "Somename", b: "b", c: 10},
    {a: "Anothername", b: "a", c: 12},
    // and so on
];
function sortList(list) {
    // Sort the list based on the 3 specific values
    list = list.sort(function(a,b) {
        a.a = a.a.toLowerCase();
        b.a = b.a.toLowerCase();
        if (a.a < b.a) return -1;
        if (a.a > b.a) return 1;

        a.b = a.b.toLowerCase();
        b.b = b.b.toLowerCase();
        if (a.b < b.b) return -1;
        if (a.b > b.b) return 1;

        if (a.c < b.c) return -1;
        if (a.c > b.c) return 1;

        return 0;
    });

    // Loop through removing duplicates
    for (var a,b,i=list.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        a = list[i];
        a.a = a.a.toLowerCase();
        a.b = a.b.toLowerCase();

        b = list[i-1];
        b.a = b.a.toLowerCase();
        b.b = b.b.toLowerCase();

        if (a.a===b.a && a.b===b.b && a.c===b.c) list.splice(i-1,1);
    }

    return list;
}
list = sortList(list);
```

Please no jQuery answers, or answers suggesting the use of another library. It seems a bit of an overkill to import a library to do something this simple.

Comment: Arrays don't have any method/property to handle duplicate entries. You'll have to implement it yourself. Preferably remove duplicate first, then sort them. Duplicate removal within a sort callback would interfere the sorting function and would likely causes error due to out of range array indexes.

Comment: Am not sure how removing the duplicates before sorting would speed this up. I'd end up having to loop multiple times over the array searching for duplicates that meet my critera(There's other values stored in the objects besides the 3 I am sorting/removing by). Could you give me an example of how to do it efficantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, I came up with an answer of my own. It still uses the two loops but this is far faster than sorting then removing duplicates, and more consistent than tracking duplicates while sorting. Basically, I loop through the array, saving each item in an object using a concatenation of the property values('key') I want to sort/remove duplicates by. If the key is already stored, I know it's a duplicate and can move on to the next. Otherwise I add the item to a new array. Once duplicates are removed I sort the array and return it:

```
function sortList(list){
    // Since the 3 properties I'm sorting by can be converted to string I can loop
    // through the specified array, creating 'keys' by concating those property values
    // and adding those 'keys' to a temporary object. If the 'key' is present in the
    // temporary object, I know it's a duplicate in the array and can ignore it.
    // Otherwise I know it's not a duplicate and add it to a new array
    for (var a=0,b=list.length,item,key="",dupObj={},nList=[]; a<b; a++) {
        item=list[a];
        key=item.a.toLowerCase()+"_"+item.b.toLowerCase()+"_"+item.c;
        if(!dupObj[key]) {
            dupObj[key]=true;
            nList.push(item);
        }
    }

    // Now that we have an array without duplicates we can sort the array:
    nList.sort(function(a,b) {
        if ((a.a = a.a.toLowerCase()) < (b.a = b.a.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a.a > b.a) return 1;

        if ((a.b = a.b.toLowerCase()) < (b.b = b.b.toLowerCase())) return -1;
        if (a.b > b.b) return 1;

        if (a.c < b.c) return -1;
        if (a.c > b.c) return 1;

        return 0;
    });

    // return the new list
    return nList;
}
var list = [
    {a: "Somename", b: "b", c: 10},
    {a: "Anothername", b: "a", c: 12},
    // and so on
];
list = sortList(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `splice` in your second loop, just put the unique values in the new array. Thus on each iteration instead of `splice`ing the existing array you will just append the value to the new array; `push` is much faster than `splice`. E.g.:

```
var newList = [];
if (list) {
    newList.push(list[0];
    for (var a,b,i=1; i < list.length; i++) {
        a = list[i];
        a.a = a.a.toLowerCase();
        a.b = a.b.toLowerCase();

        b = list[i-1];
        b.a = b.a.toLowerCase();
        b.b = b.b.toLowerCase();

        if (a.a!==b.a || a.b!==b.b && a.c!==b.c) {
            newList.push(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch(Was just editing my own script to do just that), but not what I'm seeking.

Comment: What exactly do you dislike? The filtering loop in my example is O(n) or so (depending of the `Array.prototype.push` in the specific implementation). It is negligible given you're first sorting the array (which is O(n*log(n)) at the best).

Comment: Am seeking a way to drastically increase speed. Currently I'm working with over 3k items, and my current code is hanging the page for ~2-3s. Don't get me wrong every little bit helps so I do appreciate the advice and am implementing it, but need it faster/more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code? That is, how much of the time does it spend inside the sort, and how much of the time does it spend inside of the filtering (both original version and my example)?

Comment: (You have a typo in your code, needs to be: b = list[i+1]). Not yet, though I do know the push will be faster than the splice.

Comment: (This is not a typo. newList is filled with the elements that differ from the previous element; and with the first element, since it does not have a previous). If you don't even know what parts of your code are the bottleneck, what do you mean by "not what I'm seeking"?